# Binding JSON to IEnumerable using MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 and I have the following controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Suggest(IEnumerable<Connection> connect)
{
    return Json(new { result = true });
}

public class Connection
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My JQuery looks like:

```
var connections = $('.on');
var connect = [];

$.each(connections, function (i, item) {
     var span = $(item);

     var id = span.attr('data-entity-id');
     var name = span.attr('data-entity-name');


     connect.push({ Id: id, Name: name });
 });

 $.post('myurl', connect, function (data) {
     $('.result').html(data);
 });
```

The JSON binding does not work using this code.

Comment: Care to post how the `span.on` elements are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't posting JSON. You need to stringify the data and then tell the server you're sending JSON data. In order to stringify JSON you will need to include Crockford's [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library. (That's the guy who invented JSON.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myurl",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ connect: connect }),
    contentType: 'application/json'
    success: function (data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Also, I think you might need to make your action parameter `List<Connection> connect`.