# Jquery Ajax to MVC yields unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to send a List via Ajax to my acton. At this moment, I am getting data to my action, but the data revieved are gibberish, e.g. evrything is NULL and there are 5 elements, instead of one.
I need to do collect the data via jquery because I want to dynamically expand this list.

I guess the root problem is that my JSON is somehow different from the JSOn my action expects- but I am new to this and do not see the error. The JSON send to the action is this:

```
    {
    "ideas": [
        {
            "name": "[0].ID",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "[0].Name.EnglishText",
            "value": "New Idea"
        },
        {
            "name": "[0].Name.GermanText",
            "value": "Neue Idee"
        },
        {
            "name": "[0].Description.EnglishText",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "[0].Description.GermanText",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to build a JSOn version of my list, which looks like this:
In effect totally different :(

```
"[{
    "ID":0,
    "Name":
    {
        "EnglishText":"English",
        "GermanText":"Ger"
    },
    "Description":
    {
        "EnglishText":null,
        "GermanText":null
    },
    "Project":null
}]"
```

Let me explain:
The website looks like this:

```
 <div id="collapseIdeas" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">@Model[i].Name.GetText()</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(mbox => Model[i].ID)

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                // warning: abbreviated, originally 5 inputs in this panel-body
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="ButtonDeleteIdea" class="btn btn-danger" value="@Model[i].ID">@CreateRes.DeleteIdea</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ButtonAddIdea">@CreateRes.AddIdea</button>
            </div>
```

The Ajax call used:

```
$(function () {
    $(".ButtonAddIdea").click(function () {
        var data = testFct();
        alert(data);
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: window.AddAnotherIdea,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
            }).done(function (html) {
                $("#IdeaList").replaceWith(html);
            });
    });
});

function testFct() {
    var list = $("#IdeaList :input")
    var test = list.serializeArray()
    things = JSON.stringify({ 'ideas': test });
    return things
}
```

The recieving method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> AddAnotherProjectIdea(List<ProjectIdea> ideas)
    {
    // gets called, and the List is not null - but the list appears to contain only
    // gibberish, with every value 0 or NULL. 
    //Also there are 5 elements, there should be only one
    }
```

Comment: In order to figure out what your action method expects, why not create a method that serializes a `List<ProjectIdea>` as JSON and make sure it looks like what you're sending?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy The idea is so obvious, I could bang myself with a pole....

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Unfortunetely, the result is totally different - that will be a lot of processing, before it works. I edit my question.

Comment: Look at this it might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673146/binding-json-to-ienumerable-using-mvc-3 It's the MVC model binder that could not properly bind your list to the list of Project Idea. Moreover, make sure that the field names are identical in both your Model : ProjectIdea and your JSon objects.

Comment: So you're trying to send a name-value pair collection instead of a JSON object? That's not how JSON or the binder work.